# Raycasting rendering - wall's edge crossing issue

Tags: c++, sdl-2, raycasting

I'm implementing a fake 3D rendering using raycasting method (such as Wolfenstein3D). I have following the permandi's tutorial (https://permadi.com/1996/05/ray-casting-tutorial-table-of-contents/)

As a first view, it seems to work well, but I am struggeling with an issue and I cannot figure out what happen. Indeed, the walls's edges are crossing each other and it also seems that sometimes the rays does not detect any wall.

[image]

But this not always the case. Sometimes it works well, depending the player's orientation.
[image]

After rendering the scene in 2D I can see that the rays are indeed not detecting the wall. But depending the orientation, this is not always the case.

[image]

On the screenshot above, on the left this is not working but on the right this is working.

This is how I detect the wall and get the distance and the Y axis

```
float getDistanceOnHorizontalGrid(float rayAngle, float playerPosX, float playerPosY)
{
    float pointInRayY = playerPosY + (100 * sin(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle))); // Arbitrary Point to evaluate whether ray is facing up or down
    float firstIntersectPointY;
    float ya;
    float xa;

    if (pointInRayY <= playerPosY) // ray is facing up
    {
        firstIntersectPointY = floorf(playerPosY / WALL_SIZE) * (WALL_SIZE)-1;
        ya = -WALL_SIZE;
        xa = WALL_SIZE / tan(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle)) * -1;
    }
    else // ray is facing down
    {
        firstIntersectPointY = floorf(playerPosY / WALL_SIZE) * (WALL_SIZE)+WALL_SIZE;
        ya = WALL_SIZE;
        xa = WALL_SIZE / tan(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle));
    }

    float firstIntersectPointX = playerPosX - (playerPosY - firstIntersectPointY) / tan(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle));

    float nextPointX = firstIntersectPointX;
    float nextPointY = firstIntersectPointY;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        int toMapX = convertWorldToGridCoordinate(floor(nextPointX));
        int toMapY = convertWorldToGridCoordinate(floor(nextPointY));

        if (!(toMapX >= 0 && toMapX <= MAP_WIDTH - 1 && toMapY >= 0 && toMapY <= MAP_HEIGHT - 1))
        {
            return 0.0f;
        }

        if (map[toMapY][toMapX] == 1)
        {
            return abs(sqrt(((playerPosX - nextPointX) * (playerPosX - nextPointX)) + ((playerPosY - nextPointY) * (playerPosY - nextPointY))));
        }

        nextPointX += xa;
        nextPointY += ya;
    }

    return 0.0f;
}
```

And the same for X axis

```
float getDistanceOnverticalGrid(float rayAngle, float playerPosX, float playerPosY)
{
    float pointInRayX = playerPosX + (100 * cos(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle))); // Arbitrary Point to evaluate whether ray is facing left or right
    float firstIntersectX;
    float firstIntersectY;
    float xa;
    float ya;

    if (pointInRayX <= playerPosX) // ray facing left
    {
        firstIntersectX = floorf(playerPosX / WALL_SIZE) * (WALL_SIZE)-1;
        xa = -WALL_SIZE;
        ya = (WALL_SIZE * tan(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle))) * -1;
    }
    else
    {
        firstIntersectX = floorf(playerPosX / WALL_SIZE) * (WALL_SIZE)+WALL_SIZE;
        ya = WALL_SIZE * tan(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle));
        xa = WALL_SIZE;
    }

    firstIntersectY = playerPosY - (playerPosX - firstIntersectX) * tan(DEGREE_TO_RADIAN(rayAngle));

    float nextPointX = firstIntersectX;
    float nextPointY = firstIntersectY;


    for (int i = 0; i < MAP_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        int toMapX = convertWorldToGridCoordinate(floorf(nextPointX));
        int toMapY = convertWorldToGridCoordinate(floorf(nextPointY));

        if (!(toMapX >= 0 && toMapX <= (MAP_WIDTH - 1) && toMapY >= 0 && toMapY <= (MAP_HEIGHT - 1)))
        {
            return 0.0f;
        }

        if (map[toMapY][toMapX] == 1)
        {
            return abs(sqrt(((playerPosX - nextPointX) * (playerPosX - nextPointX)) + ((playerPosY - nextPointY) * (playerPosY - nextPointY))));
        }

        nextPointX += xa;
        nextPointY += ya;
    }

    return 0.0f;
}
```

I must do something wrong, but I don't know where.
Thank you for your help

UPDATE

What Mentionned BCT was actually right even though decreasing the value from 1 is still necessary, but not in that calculation.
After taking a loog closer to permadi's implementation, after doing this

```
horizontalGrid = Math.floor(this.fPlayerY/this.TILE_SIZE)*this.TILE_SIZE  + this.TILE_SIZE;
```

He did :

```
horizontalGrid--;
```

I thought at first it's equal to what I have done but actually no. The reason he decrease the value later it's because this is only to get the grid coordinate.

To resolve my issue, I have removed the -1 from the calculation, and decrease the value only when I'm looking for the grid coordinate.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the firstIntersectPointY in the if blocks?
Also, you should probably add a code language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the link you sent. And it seems like one of the if blocks has a bad value:

This is the tutorial code:

```
// Ray is facing down
        if (castArc > this.ANGLE0 && castArc < this.ANGLE180)
        {
            // truncuate then add to get the coordinate of the FIRST grid (horizontal
            // wall) that is in front of the player (this is in pixel unit)
            // ROUNDED DOWN
            horizontalGrid = Math.floor(this.fPlayerY/this.TILE_SIZE)*this.TILE_SIZE  + this.TILE_SIZE;
```

This is your code:

```
 if (pointInRayY <= playerPosY) // ray is facing up
 {
     firstIntersectPointY = floorf(playerPosY / WALL_SIZE) * (WALL_SIZE)-1;
```

Notice you have `-1` at the end instead of `this.TILE_SIZE` which in your case should be `WALL_SIZE`

Comment: Also, it explains why it only happens when looking up and not down

Comment: I looked at his code before and I saw what you are mentionning. I thought it was the issue but this is not the case unfortunatly. I believe there is an error in this code (maybe I'm wrong). If I remove the -1 the result is getting worst. I got the -1 from his explanation, and it makes sense as the ray is facing up, we are decreasing the value on Y axis ( if I understood well)